# How to order my messed up script

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I'm new to coding and now I have problem with adding script in html page
its a web app project which has layoutpage.cshtml  and thepage.cshtml

I want to order the code which somehow sometime works sometime doesnt(most of the time) also has MAP API in the code. the problem is map doesnt load on the first time I install the app then after that works fine everytime(guess is because of cache?).
so can someone help me order this then maybe it'll fix or I'll understand and find the problem of it

problem >> map doesnt load or only map load but no pins on the first time I install my app or clear cache(if try on browser) but the problem is not happen all the time sometime works fine.
the error I catch not all of them appear at the same time but show up randomly. sometimes even the first error show up when it works.

I debug from safari(usb debug) errors I got are :

1. multipleDefine
2. defineAlreadyDefined
3. TypeError:null is not an object (evaluate 'q.renderer.toLowerCase')
4. The service is temporarily unavailable
5. setPosition : Node is undefined
6. TypeError: Object is not a constructor (evaluating 'new a')
7. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

not sure if theres more but these are the most common.

heres the layoutpage.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
    <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW">
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

here are all the scripts add in thepage.cshtml

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    @*MAP API*@
    <script type="text/javascript" src="nostra map api"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="bla bla bla" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/storageManager.js"></script>
```

as you can see there's some duplicated code.  I tried put it all in layout file delete the duplicated ones, but then it broke my javascript code so I think may be its because of how I order the code so please give me advice.
thank you.

Comment: important tip: Jquery always must be loaded first, all other scripts come after the jQuery load.

Comment: thanks for the tip. do you mean  this one?
     <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

Comment: actually it's a bit confusing because I don't know the way your web app loads, but i can see that you are loading jQuery 2 times: 1.12.4 (before RenderBody) and 3.2.1 (after @*MAP API*@). Choose one (i suggest 3.2.1), delete the other and make the chosen one load before all

Comment: I really wanna explain to you but I don't know how to since I'm also new to coding and this is write by many people and I'm here to fix it.
So I think basically this is map with search bar on top , pins on the map and a side bar that will show up when click show button.

Anyway tried what you recommended but the problem still occur. but thanks so much for the tips.

Comment: Please, debug your code and tell us what is that: "sometime doesnt(most of the time) "  which errors does you have, what happens in your code and what is the expected behavior (edit your question with those infos, please)

Comment: already updated my question thanks for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it thanks to @Calvin Nunes's advice   after trying to reorder and figure out which one is duplicated .
so I deleted out duplicated ones and put js file on top
this is it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
    <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

</head>
<body>
    @*Nostra API*@
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.nostramap.com/nostraapi/v2.0?key=Gl1ij2YtOI(AbMFsyTY(s)AJQ87ixrHtPn13RLCOi0KlqbKe6dxeTjR4RWBU3Vi0mMliHnBeUeuImFLGat6V8ym=====2"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/storageManager.js"></script>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

thanks @Calvin Nunes